# NodeJS mysql fetching related data

Tags: mysql, node.js

In my database I have two tables. Let's call them `A` and `B`. `B` table has foreign keys related to ids of records in `A` table.

I fetch couple of ids from `A` table and I want to find records in `B` table with foreign keys matching to those ids. However not every record in `A` table has records related to it in `B` table.

So in my code it looks like this:

```
var idsFromA = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

connection.query("SELECT * FROM B_table WHERE a_id = ?", idsFromA, function(err, results) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err)
  } else {
    // always empty
    console.log(results);
  }
});
```

Let's say ids number `1` and `2` from table `A` has record related to them in table `B`. Rest of them not. I want to get records from table `B` with those foreign keys but I receive only an empty array. It works only if I type query with only one matching value. But for the whole array of values where some of them don't have related record not.

How can I fix it and get information about those record?

Comment: Will there be always only one entry in B for each A, or could there be more then one entry in B for each A?

Comment: just one record in B related to one record in A is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `=` you have to use `IN` and you need to pass the array as value for the first placeholder.

```
connection.query("SELECT * FROM B_table WHERE a_id IN (?)", [idsFromA], ...)
```

The way you wrote it only the first id in the array `idsFromA` would be used for the `?`.

Instead of using two queries you might want to use a `LEFT JOIN`, and the `nestTables` option.

```
connection.query({
  query: 'SELECT * FROM A_table LEFT JOIN B_table ON (A_table.id=B_table.a_id) WHERE ...some condition to filter A...',
  nestTables: true
}, function(err, results) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
  } else {
    console.dir(results);
  }
});
```